# Getting Bing Maps to display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, bing-maps

I am currently using QGIS 3.14.

I cannot find the OpenLayers Plugin, it is not in the list, and when I add Quick Map Services Plugin, it does not have Bing maps in it (or Google Maps either).

How can I get Bing maps (satellite) to display in QGIS 3.14?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use QMS Search from the toolbar. Then search for Google, and you will find a satellite basemap as well as other basemaps:

[image]

Comment: You could also add the contributed layer ( it's somewhere in the setting), you'll get several google base map and lots of other ( not sure for bing)

Answer (score 8):

- Go to Layer > Add Layer > Add XYZ Layer..
- Click New
- Name as Bing Maps(as you wish)
- URL as `http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1`
- click Ok
- Select XYZ Connections as Bing Maps(Which you created now)
- Click Add

Comment: Do you know what the significance of the `g` query string parameter is?

Answer (score 3):

You may run a python script in order to add a lot of available XYZ-tiles to your browser permanently, including Bing Virtual Earth.

The following script was created by [Klas Karlsson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py):

```
"""
This script should be run from the Python consol inside QGIS.

It adds online sources to the QGIS Browser.
Each source should contain a list with the folowing items (string type):
[sourcetype, title, authconfig, password, referer, url, username, zmax, zmin]

You can add or remove sources from the sources section of the code.

Script by Klas Karlsson
Sources from https://qms.nextgis.com/

Licence GPL-3

Regarding the terms of use for these background maps YOU will need to verify that you
follow the individual EULA that comes with the different services,
Most likely they will restrict how you can use the data.

"""


# Sources
sources = []
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Maps","","","","https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D","","19","0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Satellite", "", "", "", "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Terrain", "", "", "", "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Terrain Hybrid", "", "", "", "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Satellite Hybrid", "", "", "", "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Stamen Terrain", "", "", "Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL", "http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Stamen Toner", "", "", "Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL", "http://tile.stamen.com/toner/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Stamen Toner Light", "", "", "Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL", "http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Stamen Watercolor", "", "", "Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL", "http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpg", "", "18", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Wikimedia Map", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, under ODbL", "https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "1"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Wikimedia Hike Bike Map", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, under ODbL", "http://tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "17", "1"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Boundaries Places", "", "", "", "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Boundaries_and_Places/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Gray (dark)", "", "", "", "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Dark_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "16", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Gray (light)", "", "", "", "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "16", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri National Geographic", "", "", "", "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "12", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Ocean", "", "", "", "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "10", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Satellite", "", "", "", "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "17", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Standard", "", "", "", "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "17", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Terrain", "", "", "", "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Terrain_Base/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "13", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Transportation", "", "", "", "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Transportation/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Esri Topo World", "", "", "", "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","OpenStreetMap Standard", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","OpenStreetMap H.O.T.", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA", "http://tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","OpenStreetMap Monochrome", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA", "http://tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","OpenTopoMap", "", "", "Kartendaten: © OpenStreetMap-Mitwirkende, SRTM | Kartendarstellung: © OpenTopoMap (CC-BY-SA)", "https://tile.opentopomap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "17", "1"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Strava All", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA", "https://heatmap-external-b.strava.com/tiles/all/bluered/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "15", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Strava Run", "", "", "OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA", "https://heatmap-external-b.strava.com/tiles/run/bluered/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?v=19", "", "15", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Open Weather Map Temperature", "", "", "Map tiles by OpenWeatherMap, under CC BY-SA 4.0", "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?APPID=1c3e4ef8e25596946ee1f3846b53218a", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Open Weather Map Clouds", "", "", "Map tiles by OpenWeatherMap, under CC BY-SA 4.0", "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/clouds_new/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?APPID=ef3c5137f6c31db50c4c6f1ce4e7e9dd", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Open Weather Map Wind Speed", "", "", "Map tiles by OpenWeatherMap, under CC BY-SA 4.0", "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/wind_new/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?APPID=f9d0069aa69438d52276ae25c1ee9893", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","CartoDb Dark Matter", "", "", "Map tiles by CartoDB, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.", "http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","CartoDb Positron", "", "", "Map tiles by CartoDB, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.", "http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Bing VirtualEarth", "", "", "", "http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1", "", "19", "1"])


# Add sources to browser
for source in sources:
   connectionType = source[0]
   connectionName = source[1]
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/authcfg" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[2])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/password" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[3])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/referer" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[4])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/url" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[5])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/username" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[6])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/zmax" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[7])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/zmin" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[8])

# Update GUI
iface.reloadConnections()
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers Plugin is an experimental plugin.

To be able to find it, you have to check **Show also experimental plugins** in the plugins settings.

[image]